# Filtering for MAX Beginning Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently getting the output of the image below. I want to be able to retrieve the latest Turn Time. Essentially the MAX beginning date and MAX end date. How Should I structure my query ?

[image]

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number()

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(parition by id order by beginningdate desc) as rn
 from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

For the larger turn time -

```
select * from
    (
    select *,row_number() over(parition by id order by turntime desc) as rn
     from tablename
    )A where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks Fahmi, that helped a ton. How would u suggest I write my query in order to retrieve the largest TurnTime?

Comment: @user13518500, I've given another piece of query - you can check that, btw, if the answer helped u please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Lastly, How would I structure my query if I wanted to retrieve the MAX Turn Time of the first two rounds. Rounds are defined as Earliest Beginning date to Earliest End Date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `order by`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
order by enddate desc, beginning_date desc;
```

If you want this per id, then you can use window functions or `top (1) with ties`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by enddate desc, beginning_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```